# Using Noethers theorem to show an expression is constant along an extremal of a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem, invariants

I am given the following integral:

$$I = \int^{t_2}_{t_1}\dot{x}^2dt $$

And the following 1 - parameter transformation:

$$\bar{x} = \alpha x\\
\bar{t}=\alpha^2t$$

I have shown that the given intergral $I$ is invariant under the given $1$-parameter transformation. That is, I have shown that $$I[x] = I[\bar{x}].$$
I now need to use Noethers theorem and the fact that the Intergral is invariant to show that $-2x\dot{x}$ is constant along an extremal of the Lagrangian

$$L(\dot{x})=\dot{x}^2$$

I somehow need to use the following to derive my answer:

> **Noethers Theorem (for a single integral):** If a Lagrangian function $L$ is invariant under the continuous $r$-parameter transformation of
> $F$. Let the infinitesimal generators of $F$ be such that $$p_i = \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}$$ and $$H=-L +\sum^{n}_{i=1} p_i \dot{x}_i .$$
> Then
>
> $$\Psi_s = H\xi_s-\sum^n_{i=1}p_i\zeta_{i,s} =\text{const. }\forall s = 1,2,...,r$$
>
> where $$\xi_s = \left( \frac{\partial \bar{t}}{\partial \alpha_s} \right)_{\alpha_s=0}\\ \zeta_{i,s}= \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x_i}}{\partial \alpha_s} \right)_{\alpha_s=0}$$

I dont know if I am interpreting or utilising the above information correctly, but I cannot show that $\Psi_s$ is constant. I dont even know the value of $s$ and therefore how many Psi's there are. I understand this is simply a matter of algebra and simple partial differentiation contained in a probably three of four steps. Could someone direct me how to use the information given?

Comment: I want to add that I did get an answer of $\Psi=-p_x x$ but dont know whether this is correct

Comment: Hint: What is $p_x$ expressed in terms of $\dot x$ ?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the very last step to re substitute the value of $p_x$ in terms of $\dot{x}$